# Save msbuild condition in variable/property

Tags: msbuild

I have a rather long condition that's used in several subsequent build tasks, all of which run when the condition is true and don't when it's false, like this:

```
<!-- In the middle of a Target -->
<Copy Condition="'$(MyProperty1)' == 'true' and '$(AnotherProperty)' == 'false' and '@(YetAnotherProperty)' != ''" ... />
<Exec Condition="'$(MyProperty1)' == 'true' and '$(AnotherProperty)' == 'false' and '@(YetAnotherProperty)' != ''" ... />
<CustomTask Condition="'$(MyProperty1)' == 'true' and '$(AnotherProperty)' == 'false' and '@(YetAnotherProperty)' != ''" ... />
```

This is pretty annoying to try and read. Is it possible to "save" this condition somehow into a variable or property of some sort? Like:

```
MyVariable = "'$(MyProperty1)' == 'true' and '$(AnotherProperty)' == 'false' and '@(YetAnotherProperty)' != ''"
<Copy Condition="MyVariable" ... />
<Exec Condition="MyVariable" ... />
<CustomTask Condition="MyVariable" ... />
```

I did find the "Choose" element, but it's not allowed in  the Target so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your requirements correctly, I think what you need can just be done by defining a property.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyProperty>False</MyProperty> <!-- defaulting to false -->
    <MyProperty Condition="...Some long condition...">True</MyProperty>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...Later

```
<Copy Condition="$(MyProperty)" ... />
```

(Note though that whether this works for your exact case might depend on the contents of the condition, due to the order in which MSBuild evaluates Properties vs Items.)